# Templated class linking error when used to declare object in other class

Tags: c++, templates, linker

I created a templated data class (`CAnyData`, please see its header file copy for your reference), with which I declared some variables in my another class (`CConstantDataBlock`, please see its header file copy for your reference). As you may see, the latter one is nearly an empty class. But when I compiled my project, the VS2008 compiler thowed the following linking errors. Would please help me figure out what's wrong with my `CConstantDataBlock` and/or `CAnyData`?

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Tips, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>ConstantDataBlock.cpp
1>Linking...
1>   Creating library F:\Tips\Debug\Tips.lib and object F:\Tips\Debug\Tips.exp
1>ConstantDataBlock.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CAnyData<double>::~CAnyData<double>(void)" (??1?$CAnyData@N@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function __unwindfunclet$??0CConstantDataBlock@@QAE@XZ$0
1>ConstantDataBlock.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CAnyData<int>::~CAnyData<int>(void)" (??1?$CAnyData@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function __unwindfunclet$??0CConstantDataBlock@@QAE@XZ$0
1>ConstantDataBlock.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CAnyData<double>::CAnyData<double>(void)" (??0?$CAnyData@N@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall CConstantDataBlock::CConstantDataBlock(void)" (??0CConstantDataBlock@@QAE@XZ)
1>ConstantDataBlock.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CAnyData<int>::CAnyData<int>(void)" (??0?$CAnyData@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall CConstantDataBlock::CConstantDataBlock(void)" (??0CConstantDataBlock@@QAE@XZ)
1>F:\Tips\Debug\Tips.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
1>Build log was saved at "file://f:\Tips\Tips\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>Tips - 5 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

---

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class CAnyData
{
public:
    CAnyData(void);
    CAnyData(int nWordNumber, string sContents, T Type, int nWidth, int nPrecision);
    ~CAnyData(void);

// Operators
    CAnyData( const CAnyData& rhs );
    const CAnyData& operator = (const CAnyData& rhs);

    // Must define less than relative to name objects.
    bool operator<( const CAnyData& AnyData ) const;

    // Compares profile's of two objects which represent CAnyData
    inline bool operator ==(const CAnyData& rhs) const;

// Get properties  
    inline int WordNumber() const { return m_nWordNumber; }
    inline const string& Contents() const { return m_sContents; }
    inline const T& DataType() const { return m_Type; }
    inline int Width() const { return m_nWidth; }
    inline int Precision() const { return m_nPrecision; }

// Set properties
    void WordNumber(int nWordNumber) const { m_nWordNumber = nWordNumber; }
    void Contents(string sContents) const { m_sContents = sContents; }
    void DataType(T Type) const { m_Type = Type; }
    void Width(int nWidth) const { m_nWidth = nWidth; }
    void Precision(int nPrecision) const { m_nPrecision = nPrecision; }

protected:
    void Init(void);

protected:
    int m_nWordNumber;
    string m_sContents;
    T m_Type;
    int m_nWidth;
    int m_nPrecision;
};

#pragma once

#include "AnyData.h"

// Constants block
// This block consists of 64 words to be filled with useful constants.

class CConstantDataBlock
{
public:
    CConstantDataBlock(void);
    ~CConstantDataBlock(void);

protected:
    CAnyData<int>    m_nEarthEquatorialRadius;
    CAnyData<int>    m_nNominalSatelliteHeight;
    CAnyData<double> m_dEarthCircumference;
    CAnyData<double> m_dEarthInverseFlattening;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you do not have definitions for several of the methods of `CAnyData`, including the default constructor and the destructor. When you use these in your `CConstantDataBlock`-class, the constructor and destructor are required though.

Since `CAnyData` is a class-template, all definitions should be [written directly into the header-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/) (just as you have done with all the getters and setters).

Comment: Dear Space_C0wb0y
I implementd all the Get/Set methods appeared in attached header file. I didn't post the corresponding cpp file.

Comment: @GoldenLee: The separation into headers and source-files does not work with class templates. See the link I provided in my answer. The simplest solution is to implement all methods directly in the header-file.

Comment: I noticed that many programmers really split them into two parts implementation, namly header (.h) and implementation (.cpp). I don't know why. It depends on compiler and linker version, right? Anyway, I'll take your suggestion, and merge the two. Thank you!

Comment: @Golden Nope, many programmers don't do that, and its not compiler or linker dependent.

Comment: Dear Space_C0wb0y and  Neil Butterworth, Thank you! I'd never split the templated data structure or class again! But I'd ever read an ebook titled "Data Structures and Algorithms with Object-Oriented Design Patterns in C++" on the web site http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus4/html/page81.html. If you have time, you could vist it.

Comment: The sample code in "Data Structures and Algorithms with Object-Oriented Design Patterns in C++" really lead a wrong way for c++ templated programming. Altough it's really a good book!

Comment: @Golden: If you want to know some really good books on C++, check out [this list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/).